# Edittext View One line

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can someone point me on how to limit the edittext as one line only?

screenshot:

[image]

my xml:

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Full Name"
 android:id="@+id/textView_data2"
 android:textSize="20sp"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:gravity="fill_vertical" />
```

Comment: maxLines should do that, anyways try setting inputType to personName

Comment: maxLines is the guy to do what you are seeking to achieve! you already have it so please take a look at your gravity and textSize.

Comment: @AshishRanjan Sweet that's what i've been looking for..haha, i will update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Full Name"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:id="@+id/textView_data2"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical" />
```

Comment: by adding inputType suggested on the top feed, the edit text behave as a single line whenever the text reached the limit size of the edit text.

Comment: add this to the answer description, it'll help people with similar issues in future.

Answer (score 0):

Just add into your XML-File `android:maxLines="1"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Full Name"
 android:id="@+id/textView_data2"
 android:textSize="20sp"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
 android:inputType="text"
 android:imeOption="actionNext"
 android:gravity="fill_vertical" />


android:inputType="text"
 android:imeOption="actionNext"
```

these two lines are the catch. you better use actionDon in imeOption

i.e., 

 `android:imeOption="actionDone"`

use this and you are all good :)

P.S. there are multiple types of imeOption provided by android. We usually use these imeOptions for our softKeyboardInput where we need to  change enter button of our keypad to anything else.
e.g., 
actionDone : DOne button
actionNext :Go to next editBox and etc, 
These imeOption only works with **inputType="text|number|..**
i.e. you need to specify a input type for using imeOption.

Hope it will help you :)